# how to get color name from hexadecimal or RGB code in android?

Tags: android

I am unable to get color name from hexadecimal code of color or RGB. I know that the combination of color is vast 255*255*255.  how can i show the color name by RGB or hexadecimal.

I tried with threshold but unable to show more color name please guide me or share any source code for java or android.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry,You can't get color name from hexadecimal or RGB code.

Comment: why guys are you down vote this question? if you dont understand please dont downvote . if you like the up vote so it can be useful to other developer

Comment: Bro,Once check guide line of StackOverFlow because some time down by them as well.

Comment: If you mean a name like "white', 'red'-  you can't.  There isn't really a strict definition, and it varies by culture.  For example, some African cultures view blue and green as the same color, while having names for many things we'd lump together as yellow.

Comment: yes thats why i am asking generalize the more colors

Comment: You can name colors whatever you want. Simply make a table with a color in a column and a given name in another column. Then use the first column as your search criterion and retrieve the other column as your result.

Answer (score 1):

You can give hexadecimal color using `parseColor` method `Color` class.

Try Color class method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

**Exmple :**

```
textView.TextColor = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
```

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve symbol 'TextColor' please help

Comment: please assume that hex code is static so  textview.TextColor will work?

Comment: please clarify the textview.TextColor.  there is no variable with textview